# how to create a data table from a not estructured text file

Tags: python, r, data-science

I create a ngram from Python and the output its something like this:

```
'vida': 113, 'sistema': 104, 'economía': 91, 'nacional': 84, 'mujeres': 76, 'derechos': 75, 'salud': 75, 'paz': 67, 'colombia': 66, 'social': 66, 'trabajo': 63, 'protección': 62, 'política': 61, 'país': 55, 'acceso': 53, 'cambio': 49, 'sociedad': 49, 'derecho': 49, 'educación': 47, 'cuidado': 46, 'así': 45, 'productiva': 44, 'condiciones': 44, 'cultura': 41, 'participación': 39, 'agua': 39, 'gobierno': 38, 'desarrollo': 38, 'integral': 37, 'construcción': 37, 'personas': 37, 'naturaleza': 35, 'territorios': 35, 'popular': 35, 'público': 35, 'pública': 34, 'territorio': 33, 'pueblos': 33, 'servicios': 33, 'todas': 33, 'población': 33, 'indígenas': 32, 'garantizaremos': 32, 'climático': 31, 'vivienda': 31, 'justicia': 31, 'políticas': 31, 'través': 31, 'producción': 30, 'cultural': 30, 'empleo': 30, 'calidad': 29, 'internacional': 29, 'manera': 29, 'pacto': 28, 'públicos': 28, 'mediante': 28, 'impulsaremos': 28, 'plan': 27, 'procesos': 27, 'territorial': 26, 'seguridad': 26, 'reconocimiento': 26, 'igualdad': 25, 'conocimiento': 25, 'afrodescendientes': 25, 'economías': 25, 'toda': 25, 'sociales': 25, 'nivel': 25, 'garantizar': 25, 'comunidades': 25, 'atención': 25, 'uso': 25, 'territoriales': 25, 'tierra': 24, 'víctimas': 24, 'transición': 24, 'trabajadores': 24, 'mayor': 24, 'programas': 24, 'enfoque': 24, 'base': 24, 'democratización': 23, 'productividad': 23, 'arte': 23, 'negros': 23, 'avanzaremos': 23, 'rurales': 23, 'públicas': 23, 'formas': 23, 'sector': 23, 'formación': 23, 'garantía': 22, 'lucha': 22, 'palenqueros': 22, 'pensión': 22, 'fin': 22, 'transformación': 22, 'marco': 22, 'culturales': 22, 'género': 21, 'sistemas': 21, 'ambiental': 21, 'modelo': 21, 'mundial': 20, 'niños': 20, 'gran': 20, 'alimentaria': 20, 'zonas': 20, 'bajo': 20, 'reforma': 20, 'potencia': 19, 'crédito': 19, 'primera': 19, 'raizales': 19, 'mayores': 19, 'fundamental': 19, 'organizaciones': 19, 'educativo': 19, 'comunitarias': 19, 'ambientales': 19, 'espacio': 18, 'industria': 18, 'jóvenes': 18, 'infancia': 18, 'niñas': 18, 'patrimonio': 18, 'alimentación': 18, 'económica': 18, 'instrumentos': 18, 'bienes': 18, 'generación': 18, 'recursos': 18, 'proyectos': 18, 'promoveremos': 18, 'laboral': 18, 'deporte': 17, 'realidad': 17, 'diversidad': 17, 'humana': 17, 'reparación': 17, 'programa': 17, 'soberanía': 17, 'garantizando': 17, 'diálogo': 17, 'mercado': 17, 'regional': 17, 'económico': 16, 'saber': 16, 'campo': 16, 'campesinado': 16, 'tiempo': 16, 'parte': 16, 'familias': 16, 'energía': 16, 'autonomía': 16, 'local': 16, 'rural': 16, 'populares': 16, 'apoyo': 16, 'fortalecimiento': 16, 'libre': 15, 'oportunidades': 15, 'haremos': 15, 'rrom': 15, 'adultos': 15, 'basada': 15, 'capacidad': 15, 'millones': 15, 'libertad': 15, 'acuerdo': 15, 'superar': 15, 'valor': 15, 'energética': 15, 'fortaleceremos': 15, 'centros': 15, 'gestión': 15, 'ser': 15, 'garantías': 14, 'agenda': 14, 'corrupción': 14, 'nuevo': 14, 'crearemos': 14, 'hombres': 14, 'superior': 14, 'general': 14, 'tierras': 14, 'espacios': 14, 'capacidades': 14, 'ingresos': 14, 'nacionales': 14, 'mejorar': 14, 'prácticas': 14, 'servicio': 14, 'control': 14, 'alrededor': 13, 'desigualdad': 13, 'convivencia': 13, 'nación': 13, 'diversidades': 13, 'saberes': 13, 'puedan': 13, 'grandes': 13, 'institucionalidad': 13, 'áreas': 13, 'riesgo': 13, 'infraestructura': 13, 'financiamiento': 13, 'transporte': 13, 'cada': 13, 'particular': 13, 'red': 12, 'vivir': 12, 'defensa': 12, 'fundamentales': 12, 'democracia': 12, 'efectiva': 12, 'permita': 12, 'colombiana': 12, 'productores': 12, 'universal': 12, 'creación': 12, 'mínimo': 12, 'permitan': 12, 'especial': 12, 'articulación': 12, 'distribución': 12, 'regionales': 12, 'hacer': 12, 'actividades': 12, 'locales': 12, 'productos': 12, 'intercultural': 12, 'tecnologías': 12, 'entidades': 12, 'sectores': 12, 'memoria': 12, 'negocio': 11, 'física': 11, 'poblaciones': 11, 'violencia': 11, 'trabajos': 11, 'impuestos': 11, 'promoción': 11, 'frente': 11, 'cuidados': 11, 'bienestar': 11, 'digno': 11, 'reducción': 11, 'dentro': 11, 'investigación': 11, 'debe': 11, 'medidas': 11, 'implica': 11, 'comunitarios': 11, 'cobertura': 11, 'incluyendo': 11, 'nuevas': 11, 'autoridades': 11, 'aprovechamiento': 11
```

I want to create a cdv file from it, that cotain two columns "words" and "Count" in a csv file, Im looking for a way fo how to do it in Python o R

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you need a python code or `R`

Comment: I prefer R @akrun but I dont care the Language

Comment: Is this in a python dictionary?

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(your_dict).T` should do the trick. or even `.stack()`

Answer (score 3):

In `tidyverse`, we can split by `:` with `separate_rows` and split the column again into two with `separate`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
tibble(col1 = str1) %>%
  separate_rows(col1, sep = ",\\s*") %>%
   separate(col1, into = c("key", "value"), sep = ":\\s*", convert = TRUE) %>%
   mutate(key = str_remove_all(key, "'"))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 261 × 2
   key      value
   <chr>    <dbl>
 1 vida       113
 2 sistema    104
 3 economía    91
 4 nacional    84
 5 mujeres     76
 6 derechos    75
 7 salud       75
 8 paz         67
 9 colombia    66
10 social      66
# … with 251 more rows
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
x <- "the string in your question"
df <- read.table(textConnection(gsub("," ,"\n" , x)) , sep = ":")

write.csv(df, "myngram" , row.names = F)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one more `tidyverse`approach:
Same as @akrun we separate the rows by `,` , then we use `str_extract` from `stringr` package twice with regex:

```
library(tidyverse)

str1 %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  separate_rows(value, sep=", ") %>% 
  mutate(key = str_extract(value, '[A-Za-z]+'),
         value = as.numeric(str_extract(value, '[0-9]+')), .before=1)
```

```
  key      value
   <chr>    <dbl>
 1 vida       113
 2 sistema    104
 3 econom      91
 4 nacional    84
 5 mujeres     76
 6 derechos    75
 7 salud       75
 8 paz         67
 9 colombia    66
10 social      66
# ... with 251 more rows
```